# How to use TinyMCE 5 API key using NPM

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I've installed TinyMCE 5 using NPM as the docs described here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#npm

And included all modules needed as described here:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/#commonjsmodules

Everything works fine as intended but I keep having this message:

```
This domain is not registered with Tiny Cloud. Please see the quick start guide or create an account.
```

I already have an API key but all docs and tutorials are showing how to use the API with the CDN only. All the docs mentions nothing about using the API key using self-hosting TinyMCE:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/#step3addyourapikey

Could anyone tell me how to use the API key without using CDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are grabbing TinyMCE from NPM you are not using our Cloud platform so there is no need for the API key at all.  Grabbing TinyMCE via NPM (or downloading a ZIP from our site) gets you the core / open source editor.

From our Cloud platform you have the ability to purchase/run a set of premium plugins beyond what is in the core / open source editor.  These premium plugins are not available on NPM.  If you want to run any of our premium features self hosted you would have to purchase them first and then we provide you with a download of the what you purchased.